# Проверка соединения с хостом TCPClient C#

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, tcp

Столкнулся с дилеммой. Есть хост к которому необходимо подключиться клиентским ПО (мое консольное приложение). При первом подключении я в цикле проверяю соединение. Но вот как проверить правильно дальнейший обрыв соединения и пере подключиться к хосту?
Менеджер:

```
public class NetworkConnectionService : INetworkConnectionLevel, IDisposable
{
    private const int RecievedBufferSize = 1028;

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly string _ipAddress;
    private readonly int _port;

    private TcpClient _tcpClient;

    public NetworkConnectionService(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _ipAddress = ipAddress;
        _port = port;
        CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }

    public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler OnDisconected;
   
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (_tcpClient != null)
        {
            _tcpClient.Dispose();
            _tcpClient = null;
        }
    }

           
    public async void ReceiveDataAsync()
    {
        var receivedData = new byte[RecievedBufferSize]; // answer buffer
        var token = _cancelTokenSource.Token;
        var isDataAvaliable = false;

        try
        {
            var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

            int receivedBytes;
            do
            {
                receivedBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);
                                 
            } while (IsConnected || !_cancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO LOG IT!
            
        }
    }
         
    public void StopDataReceiving()
    {
        _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void CreateClient()
    {
        if (_tcpClient == null)
        {
            _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToHost()
    {
        try
        {
            do
            {
                Close();
                CreateClient();

                _tcpClient.Connect(_ipAddress, _port);

                if (_tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    IsConnected = _tcpClient.Connected;
                }
                else
                {
                    OnDisconected?.Invoke(null, System.EventArgs.Empty);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            } while (!_tcpClient.Connected);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO log it 
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> KeepAliveTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_tcpClient != null)
                {
                    /// Таким образом можно определить, подключен ли еще сокет.
                    var blockingState = _tcpClient.Client.Blocking;
                    try
                    {
                        var tmp = new byte[1];

                        _tcpClient.Client.Blocking = false;
                        _tcpClient.Client.Send(tmp, 0, 0);
                        // TODO log it! Console.WriteLine("Keep alive connection is true");
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        // 10035 == WSAEWOULDBLOCK
                        if (e.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035))
                        {
                            // Still Connected, but the Send would block;
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            OnDisconected?.Invoke(null, System.EventArgs.Empty);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _tcpClient.Client.Blocking = blockingState;
                    }
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000);  //test for connection every 1000ms
            }
        });
       
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        if (_tcpClient != null)
        {
            _tcpClient.Dispose();
            _tcpClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Как работает: При конструировании объекта вызывается метод `CreateClient();` который создает экземпляр TCPClient, после конструирования нужно вызвать метод `void ConnectToHost();` Где собственно происходит соединение.

```
NetworkConnectionService _networkConnection =
            new NetworkConnectionService(ip, port);
_networkConnection.ConnectToHost();
```

Событие в менеджере `event EventHandler OnDisconected;` по идее должно срабатывать, когда свойство **Conected** будет ложно. Такое мое предположение, придумал только так.

Метод `Task<bool> KeepAliveTask()` по идее должен делать проверку, но вот я не знаю, правильно-ли так? Не будет ли блокировок и тд?
На данный момент я проверил работу только первоначального подключения (норма), с реконектом пока дилемма.

Comment: код не скомпилируется, потерян блок `try { }`

Comment: Свойство `_tcpClient.Connected` по идее и должно вам помочь.
В строке `} while (IsConnected || !_cancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested);` замените `IsConnected` на `_tcpClient.Connected`.
В KeepAliveTask возвращайте это значение. Должно решить вашу проблему.

Comment: @aepot благодарю... опечатка из-за копипасты кода.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Benedichuk благодарю за ваш совет! Буду пробовать разрывы!